# Vue component is missing template

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, vite

I have created a vue component that I have exported. I want to load the component in a different vue project. But when I add the component to the html, it gives me a warning that the component has no template or render function.
The component I want to load:

```html
<template>
  <Canvas/>
</template>

<script lang="ts">

// Import components
import Canvas from "@/views/Canvas.vue";

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    Canvas
  }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss">
@import "src/scss/app.scss";
</style>
```

The index.js in that project:

```js
import App from "@/App.vue";
export default {
    install: (app, options) => {
        app.component("App", App);
    },
}
```

I believe the component exports fine, and I think I'm missing something when importing the component in another project.
I imported the component with a tarball from `npm pack` so it is in the package.json in the new project.
This is that main.js:

```js
import {createApp} from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import Module from 'module'
import "/node_modules/module/dist/style.css"


const app = createApp(App);
app.use(Module);
app.mount('#app');
```

And this is where I use the module:

```html
<template>
  <header/>
  <main>
    <body>
    <div id="module">
      <Module/>
    </div>
    </body>
  </main>
</template>

<script setup>
import Module from "module";
</script>
```

Again I feel like I'm missing something but I can't figure out what that is.

I expected it to show me the contents of the imported component, but instead it gave me a Vue warning in the console saying: `Component is missing template or render function.`

I've also tried something like this:

```js
export default{
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    Module
  }
}
```

But that sadly didn't make a difference.

Update:

I've tried to do this in the main.js:

```js
import {createApp} from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import Module from 'module'
import "/node_modules/module/dist/style.css"

createApp(App)
    .component('Module', Module)
    .mount('#app');
```

And reference it in html like this:

```html
<template>
  <header/>
  <main>
    <body>
    <div id="s">
      <Module />
    </div>
    </body>
  </main>
</template>
```

But it gives me the same warning again and nothing is showing.

Comment: Just copy/paste `Canvas.vue` from the old project into the new one. And import it wherever you want it displayed.

Comment: That is not what I'm looking for @tao. I am trying to keep the two projects away from each other. I know it is possible to create a package like this, it is just not working for me. Currently APp.vue only loads the Canvas.vue, but in the near future it is going to be expanded.

Comment: In that case you probably want to [publish your project as a library/package](https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html#library-mode) and install it in other projects. It's a bit more advanced than regular Vue usage. Good luck.

Comment: That's what I've done. I have created a package using `npm pack` and installed that tarball in the other project. But I can't get the importing to work.

Comment: I think a better alternative solution would be using module federation instead if your use case is just sharing components between 2 separate projects.

Comment: I'm looking for a way like the vue-select package. I wan't to upload the component to npm eventually so others can import it and use it like a vue component. I've seen it been done before just the way I want it, but when I follow their tutorials and guides it does not seem to work for me. That is why I think I'm missing a thing somewhere but I can't figure it out.